# Cannot see Azure Function app in API Management service

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I deployed a new Azure Function app with HTTP trigger and Function authorization level, like the info box says. I've created a new API Management service. When attempting to import it, it doesn't appear in the list. Other ones appear but not the new one I've made and deployed the basic function to.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this issue when searching for the Azure Functions (HTTP Trigger - Authorization as Anonymous/Function Level) in APIM Service, unable to see few of them.

I have raised the MS Support ticket and did lot of troubleshooting by checking the Network Tab, creating in multiple locations, same location, with different accounts and in many other ways. But finally, it fixed automatically and its due to network issue.

Try below ways to import/add Azure Function App APIs in APIM Service:

1. Azure Portal > Azure Function App > go to the API Management option in the left Index > Select APIM Service you have created > Link API as shown in below gif:

[image]

2. You can create the API manually in the APIM Service by giving the Function App Name, URLs. For that info, refer to Adding API Manually in APIM [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually).
3. Check with the different browsers like Microsoft Edge (preferred for Azure Portal services) and Google Chrome by clearing all the cookies, cache data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did recreate both the function app and the api management service and I still get the same result. I also cannot see the APIM service from the function app, even though they are in the same resource group. I will try #2